# Start BIOS settings on Samsung 700T //BUILD when secure boot violation is shown

Tags: windows, bios, secure-boot, slate

I found the Samsung 700T slate that we got at the Microsoft Build conference. Unfortunately, upon switching it on, it shows the error message 'Secure Boot Violation'. I don't have the docking station anymore.

I've tried booting with the Windows key held, with Volume Up+Volume Down held, just either of those, connected a USB keyboard and tried various keys upon starting, but it doesn't show the Bios screen. Just the Secure Boot Violation message.

I've tried booting from a USB drive, but that obviously also doesn't work.

I'd rather not open the slate up, but if I need to, to disconnect the drive, I will.

Note: I'm planning to use this as a secondary screen for my Flight Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Volume Up</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Down</kbd> is the known combination
for entering the BIOS on boot, so you have a BIOS problem.

Disconnecting the drive will not normally help with a corrupted BIOS,
but you may try it in the hope that a missing disk will give the BIOS
a reason to enter configuration mode, where you could reset the BIOS.

If nothing helps:
Most likely, only Samsung has the tools to rewrite the BIOS.
Most likely again, they will not do so for a slate that is long out of warranty.

Comment: In the mean time I did remove the hard disk, disconnected the CMOS battery too. Without the hard disk, I got a blank screen, with just a (non blinking) cursor in the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: It looks like it's not repairable (at least not by an end-user).

Comment: Bummer. I will keep the question open though for a bit; you never know if someone comes along with the right tools....

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but managed to get into BIOS using Volume UP & DN. Disabled all the security options (thats pretty much all you get in the BIOS) and now it boots up again.

I think may have been caused by very low battery discharge as hasn't been used for several months. This is a BUILD slate too :)